# Knockout: Select Binding Returns Array of Values

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

After binding a view model to a select element, and then getting the value from that element. It returns the selected value inside of an array.

For example: The selected value is "1", the view model variable has "[1]" as its value.

```
    <label>Customer:</label>
    <select class="form-control" data-bind="options: [1, 2], 
         selectedOptions: Customer"></select>
    <button data-bind="click: $root.Click">Test</button>


    function AppViewModel() {
        var self = this;
        this.Customer = ko.observable();
        this.Click = function(){console.log(self.Customer());}
    }

    // Activates knockout.js
    var temp = new AppViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(temp);
```

[JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/cwburggrabe/Nb5Gs/1/)

I have other select elements that do this, and others that do not, and for the life of me am unable to see the difference. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you include example code for when it's *not* an array?

Comment: What is the actual question?

Comment: Sorry my question is why is the value returning as an array. QBM5 lead me in the right direction, and I feel a bit embarrassed that I didn't see my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/Nb5Gs/3/

```
<label>Customer:</label>
<select class="form-control" data-bind="options: [1, 2], value: Customer"></select>
<button data-bind="click: $root.Click">Test</button>
```

I am not realy sure what your question is, but from what I can infer.

I have always used `value` for a single selection, and `selectedOptions` when it is a multi select

Comment: It seems in that I got my binding options confused, changing "selectedOptions" to "value" solved my little mystery.